# R Programming - Using iteration value to change field names for processing for every iteraion

Tags: r

I am new to R programming, I am trying to work on below requirement. But could not achieve desired result.
Appreciate if someone can help me on this :

test dataframe :

```
 Day1.balc Day2.balc Day3.balc Day4.balc
x       100        20        30        40
y       100        10        10        10

> class(test)
[1] "data.frame"
```

My Goal is to accomplish :

```
Day2.balc <- Day2.balc + Day1.balc
Day3.balc <- Day3.balc + Day2.balc
.
.
.
Day30.balc <- Day30.balc + Day29.balc

# Testing for first 4 days 
for (i in 1:4 ) {
   test$Day[i].balc <- test$Day[i].balc + test$Day[i-1].balc
}
```

I identified the line I have written inside the loop is not the correct one, can someone help me how I can use iteration value(i), for every iteration, as a basis for changing field names since field consists of 1,2,3... for each different day( Day1.balc Day2.balc Day3.balc Day4.balc etc.,).

Answer (score 1):

We can remove the first and last column from the 'test' dataset and add the datasets together

```
Days <- test[-1] + test[-ncol(test)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I actually need all the fields as well. And I am mostly wanted to see how we can change the field names for every iteration depending on iteration number, since in my actual situation, I had to handle fields in more than 100.. count

Comment: @Vijay Your response is not clear.  Please update your post with the expected output based on the example

Comment: @Vijay If you look at the `Days` data, it is having the column names `Day2.balc, Day3.balc, Day4.balc`, so it is not clear what you wanted